# ArangoDB: How to run 2 queries in parallel in community edition

Tags: parallel-processing, arangodb

Hi I have written the below 2 queries and would like to run in these queries in parallel and not execute them sequentially. Is it possible to execute them parallelly in the community edition of the ArangoDB?

```
FOR d IN Transaction
        FILTER d._to == "Account/123" 
        COLLECT AGGREGATE length = COUNT_UNIQUE(d._id), 
                          totamnt = SUM(d.Amount),
                          daysactive = COUNT_UNIQUE(DATE_TRUNC(d.Time, "day"))
        RETURN { 
            "Incoming Accounts": length , 
            "Days Active": LENGTH(daysactive), 
            "Total Amount": totamnt 
        }
        
FOR d IN Transaction
        FILTER d._from == "Account/123" 
        COLLECT AGGREGATE length = COUNT_UNIQUE(d._id), 
                          totamnt = SUM(d.Amount),
                          daysactive = COUNT_UNIQUE(DATE_TRUNC(d.Time, "day"))
        RETURN { 
            "Outgoing Accounts": length , 
            "Days Active": LENGTH(daysactive), 
            "Total Amount": totamnt 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

of course it is possible to run multiple requests in parallel. Just fire 2 curl calls to `_api/cursor` or use 2 different `arangosh` shells.

Or run 2 curl calls in the same shell and use the `x-arango-async` header for each request to retrieve the result asynchronously as documented here: https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/http/async-results-management.html#async-execution-and-later-result-retrieval